# Laravel Join Query to get all matching records

Tags: laravel, join, eloquent, subquery

i want to get al product attributes (if any)  for the given product id using a sub query in join.

Below is my query

```
 $product_attributes = ProductAttributes::select('name as attribute_name', 'value as attribute_value')->get();

 $data['product']= Product::select('products.*','vendors.name as vendor_name','product_discounts.start_time',
            'product_discounts.end_time', 'product_discounts.discount_type','product_discounts.discount_value','product_attributes.name','product_attributes.value')
            ->leftjoin('product_discounts','products.id','=','product_discounts.product_id')
            ->joinSub($product_attributes, 'product_attributes', function ($join) {
                $join->on('products.id', '=', 'product_attributes.product_id');
            })->leftjoin('vendors','products.vendor_id','=','vendors.id')->where('id',$request->product_id)->first();
```

This query gives me following error

> InvalidArgumentException A subquery must be a query builder instance,
> a Closure, or a string.

if i use simple leftjoin with product attributes it gives me on last item from the `product_attributes` table .

can someone please guide me how can I list all the product attributes against the product without loop . Below is the table for product attributes

[image]

Comment: Have you set up any model relationships using Eloquent?

Comment: @party-ring no i did not , can you please guide me how can i use relations for this scenario

Answer (score -1):

use  ->get() instead of ->first();

Comment: how does that help ? pls elaborate

Comment: ->first(); method return one record and get() will return all matching record

Comment: example :  $orderList = DB::table('users')
    ->join('orders', 'users.id', '=', 'orders.user_id')
    ->join('order_items', 'orders.id', '=', 'order_items.orders_id')
    ->where('users.id', '=', 5)
    ->get();